# Why Same Values are being repeated for each Item

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/v8ngoyur/3/

The Item 2 doesn't got any Crustings as the crusts length is only 1 which is related to item 1

But still Item 2 is showing Crustings Value

Please let me know how to avoid that ??

[image]

This is my code

```
    var ordersplitjson =
        {
            "vendors": {
                "T1": [
                    {
                        "name": "Raj Shop",
                        "leaf": [
                            {
                                "crusts": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Quantity      1",
                                        "value": [
                                            "Crusts a",
                                            "Crusts b"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "toppings": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Quantity      1",
                                        "value": [
                                            "Topp a",
                                            "Topp b"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Quantity 2",
                                        "value": [
                                            "Topp a",
                                            "Topp b"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

var divhtmltoppcrust = '';


for (var i = 0; i < ordersplitjson.vendors.T1.length; i++)
{


    var totalitemprice = 0;
    var vendorname = ordersplitjson.vendors.T1[i].name;
    var vendoritems = ordersplitjson.vendors.T1[i].leaf;
    var vendoritemlen = ordersplitjson.vendors.T1[i].leaf.length;



    for (var j = 0; j < vendoritems.length; j++)
    {

        var toppins = vendoritems[j].toppings;
        var crusts = vendoritems[j].crusts;

        if (toppins.length > crusts.length)
        {

            for (var l = 0; l < toppins.length; l++)
            {

                for (var k = 0; k < crusts.length; k++)
                {
                    var toppingsul = '<ul>';
                    $.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {
                        if (text != '' && text != undefined)
                        {
                            toppingsul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
                            toppingsul += "</ul>";
                        }
                    });


                    var crustsul = '<ul>';
                    $.each(crusts[k].value, function(h, texter) {
                        if (texter != '' && texter != undefined)
                        {
                            crustsul += "<li>" + texter + "</li>";
                            crustsul += "</ul>";
                        }
                    });
                    var valuesss = l + 1;

                    divhtmltoppcrust += '<div class="orders-row"><aside class="left-order"><i>item ' + valuesss + '  Toppings ' + toppingsul + '  Crustings ' + crustsul + '</i></aside></div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add your expected `output` in question please...

Comment: Under Item2 the Crust a  and Crust b should not be present.

Comment: what do you mean by `item` here? `T1` or count of `toppings`?

Comment: Every array elemnet (Quantity  1) under Toppings array reperesent an Item

Comment: do the loop separately for toppings and crusts. because both array length are different. now you are doing it inside toppings array length for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the condition `if (l < crusts.length)` to add `crustsul`. And in `else` you should make empty `crustsul` like this below,

```
if (l < crusts.length) {
    var crustsul = '<ul>';
    $.each(crusts[l].value, function (h, texter) {
        if (texter != '' && texter != undefined) {
            crustsul += "<li>" + texter + "</li>";
            crustsul += "</ul>";
        }
    });
} else {
    var crustsul = '';
}
```

SEE THIS JSFIDDLE <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/v8ngoyur/10/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE:1**

To get max length for loop, you can just check this in condition like this,

```
if (toppins.length > crusts.length) 
   var max = toppins.length;
else
   var max = crusts.length;
```

Now, you can use variable `max` as loop's maximum length.

SEE THIS UPDATED-1 JSFIDDLE <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/v8ngoyur/12/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE:2**

Just add the condition `if (l < toppins.length)` to add `toppingsul`. And in `else` you should make empty `toppingsul` like this below,

```
if (l < toppins.length) {
    var toppingsul = '<ul>';
    $.each(toppins[l].value, function (i, text) {
        if (text != '' && text != undefined) {
            toppingsul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
            toppingsul += "</ul>";
        }
    });
} else {
    var toppingsul = '';
}
```

SEE THIS UPDATED-2 JSFIDDLE <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/v8ngoyur/13/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much this is working abslutely fine . How  to handle this in case if crusts array is more tan the  toppings array??

Comment: Do i need to keep an else if as shown  if (crusts.length > toppings.length)??

Comment: @PreethiJain You put that condition only for the loop max count. right?

Comment: @PreethiJain is this you want?

Comment: Hi, In case the crusts lenght is more than the toppings array length its failing at $.each(toppins[l].value, function(i, text) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59445/discussion-between-cj-ramki-and-preethi-jain).